# Adding Additional Markdown Snippets to Vim Snippets for Use When Editing Markdown Files

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ultisnips

I have `vim-snippets` installed (which, as I understand it, is basically built on top of ultisnips).

How do I add a snippet to markdown files (i.e., `.md` and `.markdown` files) such that if I type a `//` followed by a tab it converts it into a `<!-- -->` HTML comment?

Comment: Do you have ultisnips installed? But you should be able to add something to UltiSnips/markdown.snippets.

Answer (score 2):

In fact vim-snippets is a sideplugin that provides general snippets for various programming languages thorugh plugins (like: UltiSnips, snipmate, ... ) that provide snippet support to vim.
so you should first have Ultisnips and vim-snippets plugins installed at the same time. then to add your desired snippet add the following code to `vim-snippets/UltiSnips/markdown.snippets` file.

```
########################
# My Personal Snippets #
########################
snippet // "Comment"
<!-- ${1} -->
endsnippet
```

Of course vim-snippets is a general system and has some policis for writing snippets and you may after a while want to update this plugin and your custom snippets ( your personal ones ) will be gone. so its wiser to define your personal snippets in your dot files. In this case just make a file named `markdown.snippets` in `.vim/UltiSnips` folder and add the same lines of code to that file. This way your vim-snippets plugin is intact and also you have your personal snippets managed.